# Object doesn't support property or method 'set_item'

Tags: list, update

My intention is to retrieve all the entries for a project in a list and mark the field `latest=Yes` for the newest entry. I am assuming that would be the one with the biggest id.

I am able to retrieve the data and identify the max id but getting an error

> items[i].set_item is not a function when trying to update.

I saw few similar posts and tried the suggestions but still getting the same error. your help is greatly appreciated. My working code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadListData() {
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       //REPLACE the below with the name of your list as it shows up in your sharepoint
var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle( 'APP Projects' );
// var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Integrated</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
   //Declaring rows as global so that it can be accessed in the delegate functions
rows = targetList.getItems(query);
ctx.load(rows);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getDocsAllItemsSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, getDocsAllItemsFailure));
}

function getDocsAllItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
   var listEnumerator = rows.getEnumerator();
   //DEBUG statement comment this out
   console.log("Succeeded in retrieving items");
var items = [];
   while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var item = listEnumerator.get_current().get_fieldValues();
     items.push( item );
    }
   console.log(items);
  var idArray= [];
       for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
        //text += items[i] + "<br>";
        idArray.push(items[i].ID);

        //items[i].set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');
        }
    console.log(idArray);
    var maxId=Math.max.apply( Math, idArray );
    console.log(maxId);
    //processListItems( items );
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
        //text += items[i] + "<br>";
        if(items[i].ID==maxId) {
            items[i].set_item('Latest', 'Yes');
        }else {
            items[i].set_item('Latest', 'No');
        }
        //items[i].set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');
        items[i].update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {

    console.log('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function getDocsAllItemsFailure(sender, args) {
   //DEBUG statement, comment this out
   console.log('Failed to get list items. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadListData, "sp.js");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `get_fieldValues()`

If you want to use `set_item` you'll have to do that on the `item`:

```
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
     items.push( item );
}
```

But can't you simplify this some and order the result by ID descending, then the first item in the result is the item with highest ID.

Example with your code:

```
function loadListData() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle( 'APP Projects' );

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Integrated</Value></Contains></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query></View>");

    var rows = targetList.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(rows, "Include(Title, Id)");
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 

        rows.get_data().forEach(function(item, i) { 
            if(i === 0) {
                console.log("SET LATEST YES", item.get_item("Title"));
                item.set_item('Latest', 'Yes');
            } else {
                console.log("SET LATEST NO", item.get_item("Title"));
                item.set_item('Latest', 'No');
            }
            item.update();          
        });

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            console.log("ALL DONE");
        }, function(s,a) { 
            console.log("error", a.get_message());
        });

    }, function(s,a) { 
        console.log("error", a.get_message());
    });
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadListData, "sp.js");
```

Comment: That works! appreciate your help